# high performance write from tcp socket to file with scala&akka

Tags: file, scala, io, akka, actor

i'm receiving data - possibly very large files - through a socket in scala /w akka. 
So i'm wondering whats the best way for higher performance to write that chucks of data to a local file?

Thats how i receive the data:

```
def processRequest(implicit socket: IO.SocketHandle): IO.Iteratee[Unit] = {
    IO.repeat {
        for {   
            all <- IO.takeUntil(EOL)
        } 
        yield { 
            val stuffIWantToSave = all.decodeString("UTF-8")
            //how do handle this string?
        }
    }
}
```

thanks, 
Martin

Comment: Which version of Akka are you using? The above is the old IO module, if you can, you should look at the IO of Akka 2.2

Comment: well its flagged as experimental, so i'm not sure if I should implement my code using 2.2.

Comment: I'd use 2.2 given that a lot of it comes from Spray.io. I've started looking into it to and it works well.

Comment: Even if it is experimental it is way better than the 2.1 IO module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle)?

It provides both: low latency and high throughput when storing stuff to files.